# Swift dynamic programming without using inout for the cache

Tags: swift

I've been completing dynamic programming challenges. I'm trying to complete the following but get the the wrong answer with my current implementation

https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/introduction-to-dynamic-programming-1/tutorial/

The idea behind this is :

> Calculate the maximum price of wines in a list.
>
> You can only take a single wine for each year
>
> Each wine can only be picked from the end or the beginning of the wines list.
> the price of each wine is determined by wine * year
>
> the year starts at 1

When I define the cache outside the function (i.e. NOT passing as an inout parameter as in my solution here:
https://gist.github.com/stevencurtis/c265e523323be73ec823084b0707a426) rather my solution as below gives the wrong answer (49 rather than 50)

```
var mem = [[Int]]()

func dynamicMotivation (_ wines: [Int] ) -> Int {
    mem = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: wines.count), count: wines.count)
    return motivationD(wines, year: 1, ptr1: 0, ptr2: wines.count - 1, 0)
}

func motivationD(_ wines: [Int], year: Int, ptr1: Int, ptr2: Int, _ runningTotal: Int) -> Int {
    if (ptr1 > ptr2) {return runningTotal}
    if mem[ptr1][ptr2] != 0 {
        return mem[ptr1][ptr2]
    }
    let maxProfit = max(
        motivationD(wines, year: year + 1, ptr1: ptr1 + 1, ptr2: ptr2, runningTotal + year * wines[ptr1])
        ,
        motivationD(wines, year: year + 1, ptr1: ptr1, ptr2: ptr2 - 1, runningTotal + year * wines[ptr2])
    )
    mem[ptr1][ptr2] = maxProfit
    return maxProfit
}

dynamicMotivation([2,3,5,1,4]) // 50 is the optimal solution here
```

How can I use Memoization in this case without using an inout Parameter, correcting the code above to give an answer of 50 rather than the incorrect 49 as written above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't `mem` and whether or not it is passed as `inout`.  Your problem is the `runningTotal` parameter.  I have removed that parameter to match the algorithm as specified in the link, and it now returns the correct result.

```
var mem = [[Int]]()

func dynamicMotivation (_ wines: [Int] ) -> Int {
    mem = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: wines.count), count: wines.count)
    return motivationD(wines, year: 1, ptr1: 0, ptr2: wines.count - 1)
}

func motivationD(_ wines: [Int], year: Int, ptr1: Int, ptr2: Int) -> Int {
    if (ptr1 > ptr2) { return 0 }
    if mem[ptr1][ptr2] != 0 {
        return mem[ptr1][ptr2]
    }

    let maxProfit = max(
        motivationD(wines, year: year + 1, ptr1: ptr1 + 1, ptr2: ptr2) + year * wines[ptr1]
        ,
        motivationD(wines, year: year + 1, ptr1: ptr1, ptr2: ptr2 - 1) + year * wines[ptr2]
    )
    mem[ptr1][ptr2] = maxProfit
    return maxProfit
}

dynamicMotivation([2,3,5,1,4]) // 50 is the optimal solution here
```

> ```
> 50
> ```

Comment: Ok, but why? I can't see any reason that I can't pass the current total like that...

Comment: The running totals are maintained by the cache, so you are fouling up the cache values by maintaining a separate runningTotal value. Run your version and print the cache at the end and run my version and print the cache and compare.

Comment: Also note that `motivationD` has 3 places that it returns values, but you were only using `runningTotal` in one of the cases thus losing the `year * wine` value in those cases.